# Reading JSON file inside F# using Json.NET

Tags: f#, json.net, c#-to-f#

Can't deserializes JSON retrieved from a file. Get an unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in

```
let deserializedFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Files list>(json1)
```

The code follows:

```
let foo = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(jsonFile))

let json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo.Read())

let deserializedFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Files list>(json1)
```

Thanks,

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue, so that we may have a chance to help you?

Comment: What is `InnerException`?

Comment: Please provide a simple, complete, **reproducible** example of the failure, *including data files* (i.e., a small JSON file that causes the exception). If we can't reproduce the problem, we won't be able to help you solve it.

Comment: That's not an answer to your question, but why are you not using the JsonSerializer?

Comment: I have tried using JsonSerializer but I was not able to use it properly. That could be the way to go. Let me know if you know how to do it.

Comment: the comment is below:                                                                        type Files1 = {
    SourceFolder : string
    DestinationFolder : string
    CopySubFolder: bool 
}

let foo = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(@"c:\\jsonFile.json"))
let json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo.Read())
let deserializedFiles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Files1 list>(json1)

Comment: The file edited is: [
  
  {SourceFolder="e:\\foo1"; DestinationFolder="e:\\temp\\foo1"; CopySubFolder=true };
  {SourceFolder="e:\\foo2"; DestinationFolder="e:\\temp\\foo2"; CopySubFolder=true }
]

Comment: No sure how to add a file so added the inside file @rmunn. Got your question too.

Comment: please have a look @FoggyFinder.

Comment: You have invalid json. You can check here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Valid json: [{"SourceFolder":"e:\\foo1","DestinationFolder":"e:\\temp\\foo1","CopySubFolder":true},{"SourceFolder":"e:\\foo2","DestinationFolder":"e:\\temp\\foo2","CopySubFolder":true}]

Comment: So, this works for me: http://pastebin.com/mGmsYR34

Comment: @FoggyFinder I get this error when running program.fs +  $exception {"The type initializer for '<StartupCode$CodeBackup>.$Program' threw an exception."} System.Exception {System.TypeInitializationException}
I'm trying to run before call [<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

Comment: @jjpinto , you can continue in chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f ? I think, so you quickly get the answer.

Comment: @jjpinto, ping me, when you have time.

Comment: @FoggyFinder will do!

Comment: In such cases it is useful to serialize a "File list" and compare the result with the json you are trying to deserialize. If you have a json formatting error, it will pop up in the comparison.